# WMI filter to exclude/include a specific version of an application

Tags: wmi, gpo, wql

I am trying to write a **WQL query to filter computers on a version of a specific software : Firefox.**

I want to use this WMI filter on GPO to check if the version is earlier or equal or upper a specific version : 60.8.0.0 esr.

**The goal is to separate computers and users which have old versions and  computers with the new one**.

**Hundreds of computers are being reinstalled in few days with a last version 68.0 esr**. Using SCCM, it is easy to perform a clean install of a specific product like Firefox with the latest version 68esr in our case and block upgrade for the other one.
The computers which have an earlier version are in version 60.7.0.2 for the most up to date. Other older versions are also present.

Actually some parameters and homemade scripts are used to configure the browser (computers and users scope) through group policies and some parameters doesn't seem to works. I have to choose a version to apply the official ADMX from Mozilla. Since the last version, firefox.exe is able to directly read registry policies edited in a GPO and stored in `HKLM/SOFTWARE/Policies/Firefox`.

In my case I have to deal with 2 kind of Firefox:

- **New computers** with a simple new GPO (computers scope)
- **Old computers** with a GPO (users and computers scope) which copy some files with home made scripts.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to separate computers or users in different Organization Unit.
One the one hand, WMI filter seems to be the best way to do it for the new computers.
On the second hand, it will be easy to the computers which update Firefox via SCCM to be included with the new parameters without having to do it manually.

I tried this kind of WQL request:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms
WHERE (DisplayName LIKE '%Firefox%') AND (Version LIKE '60.8.0%')
```

I am not able to do it unless by listing each version to exclude/include them because `Version` seems to be a string value and I do not know how to convert it in integer or to split with the character ".".

Comment: Maybe too specific

Answer (score 0):

I've can define multiple queries on a single WMI filter and keeping in mind that querying the same WMI class multiple times can decrease performance.

It seems to work as a AND relationship as describe [here](https://www.sevecek.com/EnglishPages/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=61).

Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.

So i start to use [WMI LIKE operators and different range of character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/like-operator).
In my case :

- New computers with a newer version of Firefox ESR (older than 68.0)

```sql
SELECT DisplayName, Version
  FROM Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms
 WHERE (DisplayName LIKE '%Firefox%')
   AND ((NOT Version LIKE '[0-5][0-9].[0-9]%') 
   AND (NOT Version LIKE '6[0-7].[0-9]%'))
```

- Old computers with a newer version of Firefox ESR (greater than 68.0)

```sql
SELECT DisplayName, Version 
  FROM Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms 
 WHERE (DisplayName LIKE '%Firefox%') 
   AND ((Version LIKE '[0-5][0-9].[0-9]%') OR (Version LIKE '6[0-7].[0-9]%'))
```